# DotNetNuke edit navigation bar

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is there a decent way in DNN 7 to modify the navigation block at the top? I am completely lost.

I am using the "Awesome Cycles" content as a template for a class project. All I am trying to do is change out the word "us" in the navigation at the top for the word "me".
I'm sure there must be an easy way to do it, but I don't think I "speak the language" well enough to google this. I have been literally searching for three days, and I know I'm going to feel stupid once someone points it out but... Oh well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: of course... less than five minutes after posting I find it.

Just in case someone else needs the help: All you have to do is edit the titles of the pages already in DNN by opening the edit menu on the page who's title you wish to change, and selecting "Page Settings". The "Page Name" is what you need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you can simple change the Page Name in the page settings to control what displays in the Navigation. But be aware that changing a page name also changes the URL of that page.

Check out this video for how to avoid bad URLs after changing pages

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/213/View/Details/Renaming-a-Page-in-DotNetNuke.aspx

tl;dr - create a new page, with the old name, make it hidden (not in the menu), and have it redirect to the new page.